# ReactCSSTransitionGroup different transitionEnterTimeout for each item

Tags: reactjs

I can animate block of 10 items like this:

```
render() {
       const feedbackList = this.props.feedbackList.map((oneFeedback,index) => {

        return (
          <FeedbackItem feedback={oneFeedback} language={this.props.language} key={oneFeedback.Code.toString() }/> 
        )
    }); 
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                 <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName = "feedbacks" transitionEnterTimeout={500}  transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                <div key={index.toString()}>  
                    {feedbackList}
   </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

But I would like to animate them in different times for each item. Something like this:

```
  render() {
      const feedbackList = this.props.feedbackList.map((oneFeedback,index) => {
        return (
            <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName = "feedbacks" transitionEnterTimeout={index*500}  transitionLeaveTimeout={index*500}>
                <div key={index.toString()}>
                    <FeedbackItem feedback={oneFeedback} language={this.props.language} key={oneFeedback.Code.toString() }/>
                </div>
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        )
    }); 
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                    {feedbackList}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Notice how I'm set transitionLeaveTimeout different for each item, to have effect that each item fades from left in different times, but this approach does not work. How to make different transitionEnter timeout for each item?